# Multiple suggestions for duplicates when closing and flagging questions

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Come across this situation occasionally and looking for people's opinions on how to handle it.

Question is an obvious duplicate find a question that fits the bill and flag / close as a duplicate of that question. Problem is that after a bit more digging the question actually is slightly different and fits a different question while still being a duplicate.

Now in this situation the dialogs have changed;

#### Voting to Close

Only option is to retract your vote but doing so means you can't vote again using the different duplicate.

#### Flagging as Duplicate

Duplicate option is gone so the different duplicate cannot be suggested.

I can understand why changing a duplicate after its voted to close could be an issue, but just wondering if there is a better way of handling this scenario. At the moment I post a comment along the lines of;

> Possible duplicate of ...

Then hoping moderators / those reviewing the close request would see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the moment I post a comment along the lines of; ...

I think that's the best option to choose.

Other close voters that like to agree on your 1st choice, might also agree for your second, subtly better one. That gives them the chance to turn the wheel.